# Attempted import error: 'CSmartTable' is not exported from '@coreui/react'

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

How can I implement the CSmartTable in React-JS?

Is it the coreui component or there is some module that I have to install before?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature for coreUI pro version. https://coreui.io/react/docs/4.0/components/smart-table/